# MySQL errno 150 when running create table script

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

I am building create scripts for my database, and am getting an error I cannot figure out.  I have traced it down to a foreign key reference, but a Google search of the errno(150) has not been particularly helpful.

The script that fails:

```
create table ITEM_TBL(
IT_ITEM_ID_FLD INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
IT_ITEM_NAME_FLD VARCHAR(50),
ITY_ITEM_TYPE_FLD INT,
UT_USER_ID_FLD INT,
IT_CHECKOUT_STATUS_FLD VARCHAR(1),
IT_LAST_UPDATE_FLD DATE,
IT_LAST_ITEM_CHANGE_FLD DATE,
IT_ACTIVE_FLD VARCHAR(1),
PRIMARY KEY (IT_ITEM_ID_FLD),
FOREIGN KEY (UT_USER_ID_FLD)
REFERENCES USER_TBL(UT_USER_ID_FLD),
FOREIGN KEY (ITY_ITEM_TYPE_FLD)
REFERENCES ITEM_TYPE_TBL(ITY_ITEM_TYPE_FLD)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

(NOTE: it is the last foreign key that is causing the error, because when it is removed it works perfectly)

The foreign key referenced tables:

```
create table ITEM_TYPE_TBL(
ITY_ITEM_TYPE_ID_FLD INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
ITY_ITEM_TYPE_NAME_FLD VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (ITY_ITEM_TYPE_ID_FLD)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

create table USER_TBL(
UT_USER_ID_FLD INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
UT_NAME_FLD VARCHAR(50),
UT_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FLD VARCHAR(50),
UT_CARD_NUMBER INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (UT_USER_ID_FLD)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

The specific error I get is:

> #1005 - Can't create table 'db.ITEM_TBL' (errno: 150)

Comment: It looks like `ITY_ITEM_TYPE_FLD` doesn't exist in `ITEM_TYPE_TBL`. Did you mean to use `ITY_ITEM_TYPE_ID_FLD`?

Comment: That is the problem, thanks.  I probably overlooked that ten times.

Comment: I'll say those table and column names are pretty code-blindness-inducing.  `ITY_ITEM_ITY_TYPE_ITEM_FLD_ID` :)

Comment: the goal of them is actually to be easier to remember and follow a code standard.  Since every primary key ends in ID_FLD I should have figured out the problem earlier, but I agree the similar names make it harder to spot problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your tables (with indexes) already exist before creating the foreign key relationship.  Like this

```
create table USER_TBL(
  UT_USER_ID_FLD INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UT_NAME_FLD VARCHAR(50),
  UT_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FLD VARCHAR(50),
  UT_CARD_NUMBER INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (UT_USER_ID_FLD)
  )ENGINE = INNODB;

create table ITEM_TYPE_TBL( 
  ITY_ITEM_TYPE_ID_FLD INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ITY_ITEM_TYPE_NAME_FLD VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (ITY_ITEM_TYPE_ID_FLD)
  ) ENGINE = INNODB; 

create table ITEM_TBL(
  IT_ITEM_ID_FLD INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  IT_ITEM_NAME_FLD VARCHAR(50),
  ITY_ITEM_TYPE_FLD INT,
  UT_USER_ID_FLD INT,
  IT_CHECKOUT_STATUS_FLD CHAR(1),
  IT_LAST_UPDATE_FLD datetime,  
  IT_LAST_ITEM_CHANGE_FLD DATE,
  IT_ACTIVE_FLD CHAR(1),
  primary key (IT_ITEM_ID_FLD),
  FOREIGN KEY (UT_USER_ID_FLD) 
  REFERENCES USER_TBL(UT_USER_ID_FLD) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (ITY_ITEM_TYPE_FLD) 
  REFERENCES ITEM_TYPE_TBL(ITY_ITEM_TYPE_ID_FLD) 
  ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

BTW, you also had a typo (ITY_ITEM_TYPE_ID_FLD vs ITY_ITEM_TYPE_FLD)

This works in sqlfiddle

Comment: Yes, my table dependencies are fine.